# Windows 7 intense flickering checkerboard colors allover

Tags: windows-7

As you can see in the image, my win 7 pc started flickering with intense colors in a checkerboard kind of pattern, all over my two monitors. The UI was still functional as I turned it off. Then I took it from the socket. After restarting it, the error is gone the pc is running fine.

I would really appreciate if someone could point me in a direction, what the problem could be and was to start looking. 
Win 7 Pc runs smoothly for about 2 years. Had the same error a few months ago. After a restart pc runs normal again this time and last time.

Specs:
Mainboard: Gigabyte Z170-Gaming K3
CPU: Intel Core i7 6700K 4GHz
GPU: Nvidia Geforce GTX 970, 4GB
Ram: DDR4 HyperX 2400MHz, 32GB (Dual Channel, 4x 8GB)
PSU: be quiet! Pure Power 600W (BQ L8-600W)
2x internal SSD, 256 and 1TB and 1x HDD, 1TB

Thanks for the help,
AM

[image]

Comment: Usually this denotes a bad video card or a memory error. Are you using onboard graphics or a video card? What PSU?

Comment: Bad video as suggested or possibly an intermittent circuit on the motherboard related to the video circuit. How old is the machine?  It has been some years since Windows 7 was new.

Comment: @NatsuKage thank you for the reply. I updated my specs. Is there a tool you could recomend to test those errors, or would you think that this will worsen or result in a total failure in some time. Im a bit nervous because im 1,5 month before my exam and im dependent on my pc for it.

Comment: @John tank you John for your suggestion. I bought this machine prebuilt 3.2016 from CSL and currently added 1x SSD 1TB and 2x 8GB ram.

Comment: I'd check your PSU cables, especially on the videocard. There's been reports that a failed PSU gave this kind of errors on the 970. Did the error perhaps start after you added RAM though?

Comment: Thank you, I will check it out. No I added the additional ram two weeks ago and the error occured last night. Also it has happened before once, but vanished like this time.

Comment: You know, Windows 7 license(product key) will work for Windows 10 - with that in mind I would extract my data and do an upgrade/fresh install of W10. If Error persist after that(new drivers), switch between integrated and dedicated GPU if problem does not lie in GPUs, test the Monitor, and check the PSU(install one thats known to be healthy).

Comment: @Leshy thank you for you suggestion. Ill try that in 1.5 month when my exam is done, before that upgrading to windows 10 is to risky and time intensive.

Comment: Either way, good path, as already stated by others, is: Check drivers, Check your video cables, reseat them, Check GPUs(both int. and ded.(reseat it) and third one if you have it laying around), Check PSU(test your system with one that's known to be good, or at least check/reseat the PS connectors on your motherboard).